# JavaScript is not working (even it did it before)

Tags: javascript, html

I was working in a php file, and I have a few divs that are hidden at first. Later, when I press a button/a (it doesn't matter in this case), a JavaScript function makes visible a div, and hide the others.

My problem is this: the last time I modified the file, all worked fine. However, I have just prove it, and the JavaScript doesn't work, and I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function showdata(){
            document.getElementById('configure').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('delete').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('data').style.display='block';}</script>
            <li><a class="lista" id="adata" href="#adel" onclick="showdata();">This should activate the script.</a>
```

"data" is the div that is hidden at first. The other functions are similar to this, with a 'a' that runs the js code.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

---

The console error when I tried to use the JavaScript is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I tried to fix the error with some resolved questions about this, but without any success. That code works in other files, so I am not sure about the nature of the error.

Besides, all divs are fine, with the correct id assigned.

Comment: Have you looked at the developer's tools in your browser? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The most likely reason is that you made a typo when editing, so none of the code is running. There will be an error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Tested alone your code works perfectly. See the code snippet below.
Check your console for error logs, and try posting a demonstration in a snippet in your question, if you can show the code in the context in which it fails it will be possible to assist you to troubleshoot.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">function showdata(){
            document.getElementById('configure').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('delete').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('data').style.display='block';}</script>
            <a class="lista" id="adata" href="#adel" onclick="showdata();">This should activate the script.</a>
<div id="configure">configure DIV</div>
<div id="delete">delete DIV</div>
<div id="data">data DIV</div>
```